# SubD creates a crease in an edge

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have an issue with my SubD model which seems to be creating a crease on a random edge. I checked double vertex but it's not that. And there is no Crease applied on this corned as you can see. Do you know how to get rid of this creased edge?
I am using Blender 2.83.5

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This can happen when your normals are flipped on part of the mesh.  Pretty common with *Mirror* operations.

The problem is that the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* is interpolating between the inside and the outside of the mesh, at this point, so for the vertices in between they are returned to their original positions.

[image]

To diagnose problems like this you can check face orientation overlay in this menu.

[image]

Typically you want the blue side facing the camera.  If you see any red you can tab into edit mode, select all your mesh and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or go to the menu *Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside*.

[image]